# repeat code automatically

Tags: c++

I wrote some code to convert any string to Morse code. The code works perfect until I try repeating it automatically.

Whether I use "while" or "do while" the code runs only once and then it terminates.
Would you help to find out what the problem is?

```
int main ()
{
    cout<<"Enter the string: ";
    char myStr[81];
    char ch='y';

    while (ch=='Y'||ch=='y')
    {
        getString(myStr);
        toUpper(myStr,strlen(myStr));
        removeSpace(myStr);
        getMorse(myStr,strlen(myStr));
        cout<<"to repeat press Y/y";
        cin>>ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added the getString() function

```
void getString(char myStr[])
{
  cin.getline(myStr,81,'\n');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging and stepping through your code and/or printing out intermediate values?

Comment: There might be leftover input, but you'd probably notice it skipping over the input statement at the end of the loop.

Comment: Need to see the code for `getString`, as chris says, probably left over input.

Comment: Chris is right.  My guess is that "getString()" is doing its own keyboard input ... and perhaps interfering with "cin>>ch".

Comment: how can I clean any leftover before asking for the ch character?

Comment: @femchi, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user enters input, they press enter. That newline character `'\n'` is still in the `cin` stream. You need to `ignore` it:

```
cin >> ch;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //this ignores all subsequent characters until the newline character
```

Comment: I learned you should also clear it before calling ignore, i.e. `cin.clear()`